# On Android, how can I see from within the app (premium app) itself if a user has paid for the app?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, in-app-purchase

I know this has been asked many times before but a lot of them are very old so I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this now (couldn't find anything myself). The reason why I need this is because I am planning to convert a paid app I have to a free one with IAPs and I want to grant the in-app purchases for any user who has paid for the app previously.

I think on iOS there is this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction

Is there something similar for android?